# Using ServiceStack.OrmLite how can I add a bool column with a default value?

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

I'm using C# and the latest version of ServiceStack.OrmLite (4.0.33) and I'm trying to add a column of type `bool` to an existing table with existing data.  I get the obvious error that I cannot add a column to an existing table because of null values and the new column does not have a default value.  Looking at the `Default` attribute I don't see where I can set the default value to be `false`.  I don't want the column to allow nulls.  I can't imagine this hasn't been done before.

As always, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On ServiceStack 4.0.36 with Azure SQL server I was able to use:

```
  [Default(typeof(bool), "0")]
```

For the "false" default value on a boolean (bit) field.

Comment: This was the only place I could find an example of this attribute being used, then I can see it https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/DataAnnotations/DefaultAttribute.cs

Comment: Any idea how to do this with strings? I always get an error if I do typeof(string), "Default" ...

Comment: (better late than never) @jxtra the default for strings would not need the typeof e.g. [Default("Some value")]

Comment: For SQLite the `bool` property is stored as `INTEGER` so it was sufficient to use `[Default(0)]`.

Comment: @jxtra SQLite needs inner quotes as well ”’Default’”